# Retrieve location from Firebase and put marker on google map

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

I created the database in Firebase and tried to show the marker in the map. Still not working. what should I do. The app runs but when map activity is opened the app closes. I creates the database manually. I referred this link :- [Retrieve location from Firebase and put marker on google map api for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635994/retrieve-location-from-firebase-and-put-marker-on-google-map-api-for-android).

This is the code

Map Activity

**map.java**

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.EventListener;

public class map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

     FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
     DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
     String nameddd;
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        nameddd = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Location").child("Name").toString();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mDatabaseReference = mDatabase.getReference("Location");
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                LatLng newLocation = new LatLng(dataSnapshot.child("Latitude").getValue(Long.class),dataSnapshot.child("Longitude").getValue(Long.class));
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newLocation).title(nameddd)
                );
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }}
```

This is the Firebase database structure

```
Location
   |-2JHHhnUhYKVzAmoDvrhtUJfhGEg2
         |- ABpos: "20"
         |- Latitude: "12"
         |- Longitude: "22"
         |- Name: "Sion"
```

Logcat

```
Process: com.bloodapp.blood, PID: 5393
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to long
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertLong(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:384)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToPrimitive(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:295)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:214)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:203)
        at com.bloodapp.blood.map$1.onChildAdded(map.java:54)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ChildEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: All the values stored in database are in string format

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo i added the logcat entry. **map.java** is the map class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to long

Because you are trying to get the value of the `Latitude` property as a `Long`:

```
dataSnapshot.child("Latitude").getValue(Long.class)
```

While in your database is stored as a String.

```
|- Longitude: "22"
```

See the equation marks?

To solve this, you should change the type for your `Latitude` and `Longitude` properties in the database to be of type `double` and **not** String:

```
|- Longitude: 22.01
```

And get them accordingly:

```
double lat = dataSnapshot.child("Latitude").getValue(Double.class)
```

The latitude and longitude cannot be `long` numbers, it should be `double` and this is because both contain decimals.